# I'm trying to create my own (elem) function

Tags: list, haskell, search

```
myElement [] = []
myElement [h] = [h]
myElement (h:t)
| h == myElement t  = True
| otherwise         = False
```

Hi guys, I'm struggling creating my own `elem` function, because I'm not allowed to use any predefined function in haskell for homework. I bet my code is not actually working but I can't think other way else.

Comment: Shouldn't your `myElement` take two parameters?

Comment: Why not ask the prof setting the homework?  They will be best placed to explain in the context of the rest of their teaching.

Comment: "I bet my code is not actually working" if you tried it, it'd give you an error message with an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that your function only works with one parameter, whereas `elem` will take two parameters: the *needle* (we are looking for), and the *haystack*.

This thus means that `myElem` has as type:

```
myElem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

another problem is that `myElem [h] = [h]` makes not much sense, if you have a list with one element, you should not return that element, but you should, just like every clause, return a `Bool`.

As for the last clause, if `h` is not the element we are looking for, we need to use recursion to look for the remaining haystack.

The function thus looks like:

```
myElem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
myElem x = go
    where go [] = … a Bool …
          go (h:t)
              | x == h = …
              | otherwise = … recursive call …
```

where you need to fill in the `…` parts.

Comment: err, why is where go [] = False not working... I was  trying that first and treated others as comment.

Comment: What do you mean with not working, if you put the rest in comment, and you use a non-empty list, then Haskell does not know what to do with a non-empty list, and thus it will error.

Comment: it returns error instead, of false when I gave an empty list

Comment: @EthanLim: but you called with with a *needle*, right (the item to search), so `myElem 4 []`. In this `4` is the item we are looking for, and `[]` the "haystack" where we look for the element.

Comment: why is it x==h instead of h==x.

Comment: @EthanLim: `x == h` is equivalent to `h == x`, since a equivalence relation needs to be *symmetric*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation